# divergence of $\sum_{k_1\neq k_2\neq \dots \neq k_n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\dots p_n^{k_n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, divergent-series

Let $p_1=2<p_2<p_3<\dots$ are consecutive prime numbers.

Let $$S_n=\sum_{k_1=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k_2=0}^{\infty}\dots \sum_{k_n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\dots p_n^{k_n}}$$

It is easy to check that $S_1=2,S_3=3$ and in general $S_n=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p_1}}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p_2}}\dots \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p_n}}$

Then if we can show that as $n\to\infty$, $S_n$ diverges to infinity we can say $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ also diverges to infinity.

If we can show that $S_n\thicksim f(n)$, where $f(n)$ increases to infinity as $n\to\infty$, then we are done.

### What is this $f(n)$?

### Is there any other way to show $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}$ diverges using $S_n$?

---

But I have no idea about the following problem:

$$T_n=\sum_{k_1\neq k_2\neq \dots \neq k_n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\dots p_n^{k_n}}$$

Here $k_1\neq k_2\neq \dots\neq k_n$ means they are distinct($n!$ values).

#### How should we proceed to in this case?

Comment: You don't really need very precise estimates, but if you want you can show $S_n \sim e^\gamma \log(n)$, see e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341369/estimating-size-of-partial-euler-product

Comment: @Winther thanks! But you said `You don't really need very precise estimates` , how to show diverges using $S_n$ otherwise?

Comment: The title seems to be a tad misleading.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt can you please suggest one, thanks.

Comment: Multiple prime zeta function?  A combo of prime zeta and multiple zeta

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks for those topics... I did not know those topic even exited(ha ha).... anyway by wiki definition this is not multiple zeta function and saying prime zeta would be bad.... it is far much easier than those things!

Comment: Ah yes, I certainly read that wrong xD

Comment: @MANMAID How did you arrive at the calculation relating $T(n) = S(n)$?  You didn't define the notation $k_1\ne k_2 \ne\cdots \ne k_n$, but it would be natural to think it means "$k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n$ are distinct".  However, the calculation suggests that you really mean "$k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n$ are not all identical", which is a very different criterion.  Of the index sets $(k_1,k_2,k_3) \in \{ (1,1,2), (1,2,1), (3,2,1) ,(1,2,3) \}$, which of these four is included in your summation?

Comment: @ErickWong First I do not wish to show $T(n)=S(n)$, on the other hand you are very right and obviously my calculation was wrong (So I deleted that part!). $k_1\neq k_2\neq \dots\neq k_n$ means they are distinct($n!$ values). Thanks.

Comment: @MANMAID Thanks, I meant to say "relating $T(n)$ to $S(n)$".  The $=$ sign was left over from an earlier draft.

Answer (score 2):

**A hint:** since
$$S_n=\frac{p_1}{p_1-1}\frac{p_2}{p_2-1}...\frac{p_n}{p_n-1}$$

From [Mertens' 3rd theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems)
$$0<(1-\varepsilon)e^{-\gamma}<\ln{p_n} \cdot \prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{p_k-1}{p_k} < (1+\varepsilon)e^{-\gamma}$$ or
$$\frac{\ln{p_n}}{(1-\varepsilon)e^{-\gamma}}>\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{p_k}{p_k-1} > \frac{\ln{p_n}}{(1+\varepsilon)e^{-\gamma}}$$
Altogether
$$C_1\cdot \ln{p_n} > S_n>C_2\cdot \ln{p_n}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know Mertens' 3rd theorem.

Comment: Again can you say if $T_n$ diverges or not... **yes or no** at least!

Comment: I need to think about it, I only recalled Mertens' theorem because I used it a few times in past, like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726488/finding-an-upperbound-for-sum-i-2n-bigg-prod-k-2i-dfracp-k-2p-k/1726523#1726523

Comment: @MANMAID Otherwise try bounding $T_n$ below by a function of $S_n=\prod_{p \le n} \frac{1}{1-1/p}$, that $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n$ diverges implies your series diverges