# Minimum and maximum of a partial Euler product?

Tags: calculus, analytic-number-theory, maxima-minima, l-functions, euler-product

> ***Question:*** If if $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $s\in \mathbb{C},$ say $s=\sigma+t\sqrt{-1},$ then Dirichlet Beta function is defined to be
>   $$
> \beta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^s};
> $$
>   which  for Re(s)>1, has the Euler product representation over prime numbers $p:$
>   $$
> L(s)=\prod_{p>2}{ 1\above 1.5pt 1-(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p^{-s}};
> $$
>   equiv.,
>   $$
> \prod_{p \equiv 1 \pmod 4}\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} \prod_{p \equiv 3 \pmod 4}\frac{1}{1+p^{-s}}.
> $$
>   If $x$ is a positive number I write $L_x(s)$ where for the above product is restricted to those odd prime numbers that are less than or equal to $x.$ I set
>   $$
> m(s)=\operatorname*{min}_{x} L_x(s)
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> M(s)=\operatorname*{max}_{x} L_x(s)
> $$
>   Can we show that $m(s)$ and $M(s)$ exist and compute (estimate) there values ?

---

Since the product converges I am certain $L_x(s)$ is bounded and so has a maximum ? For example I think I have correctly that 
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}L_x(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}
$$
This is just the Euler product representation of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and so $L_{x}(1)$ is the partial Euler product up to some magnitude $x.$ I would like to make the claim that over all $x$ that $\operatorname*{min}_{x} L_x(1)=\frac{3}{4}
$ and that $\operatorname*{max}_{x} L_x(1)=\frac{15}{16}.$ That the minimum might be equal to $\frac{3}{4}$ might straightforward but even there I am not certain.

---

Similar but not quite the same question:

1. [Partial Euler Products](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341369/estimating-size-of-partial-euler-product)
2. [how to prove that the partial euler product of primes less than or equal x is bounded below by log x](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/567350/how-to-prove-that-the-partial-euler-product-of-primes-less-than-or-equal-x-is-bo)

Comment: Do you mean to put $s=1$ in your definitions of $m$ and $M$?

Comment: @Kimball , no that was for a complex $s$ in general but I am most interested in the case $s=1.$

Comment: In any case, because of the way the terms alternate, it's reasonable to expect the min and max occur when you have a minimal number of terms in the product.  E.g., for $s=1$, the max is 1 (empty product) and we guess min is 1(1+1/3).  One can probably prove this with a mix of computations and error bounds.

Comment: @Kimball how can formalize what you have suggested to improve my question, so I might edit it ?

Comment: I think your question is understandable, though it will be a little clearer to write $m(s)$ and $M(s)$ as they depend on $s$.  It might help you to understand what is going on to compute some partial Euler products and see how the partial products oscillate.  The main issue to prove that the first 2 partial products are max and mins is that the primes don't perfectly alternate between 1 and 3 mod 4.  But I checked for products with $p < 10000$ and it seems true.

Comment: @Kimball, maybe assume they do alternate perfectly (no bias). Is that sufficient to get a solution going ?

Comment: Yes, because then the terms would alternate as > 1 and < 1 and the even/odd terms would tend to 1 monontonically (the product version of an alternating series with terms strictly decreasing in magnitude).

Comment: The $p$s in the numerator of the double product are a typo. Also presumably one wants $s$ to be real for max and min to make sense (unless one invokes absolute values).

Comment: That $\sup_x,\inf_x\sum_{p \le x}(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p^{-s}$ exist for $\Re(s)>1$ is obvious. I don't know what you expect antonio, see how it works for the partials sums $\zeta_x(s)=\sum_{n\le x} n^{-s}$ of $\zeta(s)$, it is very hard to know by advance what will be $\sup_x |\zeta_x(s)|$ especially for $\Im(s)$ large. For the sums over primes we have that the $\log p$ are $\Bbb{Q}$-linearly independent so we can choose $\Im(s)$ to set $arg(p^{-s})$ as we wish.  (In Titchmarsh) there are a lot of exponential sums theorems whose purpose is to understand how those things work.

Comment: See @Kimball comments : "it's reasonable to expect the min and max occur when you have a minimal number of terms in the product..." In the case of $L(1)$ one approach is to use the fact that $p/(p+1)<p/(p-1)$ and assume that both residue classes are equally distributed up to $x$ e.g. one does not occur more often than the other. Use the fact and the assumption to find smallest $x$ such that the min and the max can be found by brute force computing $L_k(1)$ for all $k<x.$

Answer (score 1):

With $$\mathfrak{M}(s) = \sup_x\ \Re(\sum_{p \le x} (-1)^{(p-1)/2} p^{-s}), \qquad \Re(s) > 1$$

the $\Bbb{Q}$-linear independence of the $\log p$ implies $\lim_{k \to \infty} \mathfrak{M}(\sigma+it_k) = \sum_p p^{-\sigma}$ for a sequence $t_k\to \infty$ where each $t_k$ is the imaginary part of a zero of $\beta(s)-\zeta_2(\sigma)$. Moreover $\beta(s+it_k)$ converges uniformly to $\zeta(s)$ on $\Re(s) \ge 1+\delta$ and the same holds for the partial sums of their Euler product :

For $\epsilon> 0$ small enough, if $\mathfrak{M}(\sigma+it)$ is $\epsilon$-close to $ \sum_p p^{-\sigma}$ then $\beta(\sigma+it)$ is $\epsilon$-close to $\zeta_2(\sigma)=(1-2^{-\sigma})\zeta(\sigma)$ and $\beta'(\sigma+it)$ is $\epsilon$-close to $\zeta_2'(\sigma)$, and since $\beta''(s)$ is bounded it means there is a zero of $\beta(s)-\zeta_2(\sigma)$ at $s = \sigma+it+\frac{ \zeta_2(\sigma )- \beta(\sigma+it)}{\zeta_2'(\sigma)} + O(\epsilon^2) = \sigma+it + O(\epsilon)$.

In other words the rate of convergence of $\sup_{t \le T} \mathfrak{M}(\sigma+it) \to \sum_p p^{-\sigma}$ depends on the density of zeros of $\beta(s)-\zeta_2(\sigma)$ around $\Re(s)=\sigma$.

The latter is research level, there are some methods and results about it in the literature.